# Why doesn't Google Instant work for me?

Tags: google-search

Even though I have signed in, cleared all cache/cookies [Google Instant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Search#Instant_Search) still doesn't work for me. How can it be fixed?

[Edit]

The URL I use is [www.google.com.vn](http://www.google.com.vn).

I see the dropdown keyword suggestion list but the search result doesn't change when I select a new keyword.

I'm using Google Chrome browser with the default settings.

The strange thing is that I can use Google Instant at home while I cannot do this in my office!

Comment: What is the current url you are entering in Google Instant?

Comment: Do you even see the option (turn on/off)? Do you see the auto-suggest drop down? Have you got javascript disabled?

Comment: You can try another browser like [Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome)

Comment: @chanchal1987: In fact, I'm using Chrome

Comment: @Nam Gi VU: Actually I am from India. I tried [http://google.co.in](http://google.co.in) and [http://google.com.vn](http://google.com.vn) . Both works for me. You can try [http://google.com](http://google.com) or [http://google.co.in](http://google.co.in) or [https://google.com](https://google.com) .

Comment: You can also try from another browser like [Mozilla Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/firefox.html) or [Internet Explorer](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/default.aspx).

Comment: @Nam Gi VU: If you want to make a discussion room for this question then you can try [chat.<link to your question>](http://chat.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7125) (From [Chat post](http://chat.webapps.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/525#525))

Answer (score 4):

From the [Google Instant FAQ](http://www.google.com/instant/) -

> Google Instant is starting to roll-out
>   to users on Google domains in the US,
>   UK, France, Germany, Italy, Spain and
>   Russia who use the following browsers:
>   Chrome v5/6, Firefox v3, Safari v5 for
>   Mac and Internet Explorer v8. Please
>   note, users on domains other than
>   Google.com can only access Google
>   Instant if they are signed in to a
>   Google Account. We will continue to
>   add new domains and languages over the
>   next several months.

If you are not seeing it, its likely that either Google Instant has not rolled-out in your country or you are not signed-in while searching or you may be using a browser that they don't support.

Comment: But I am from India and I can access Google Instant from www.google.co.in and www.google.com.vn both.

Comment: I signed in already and it doesn't work still

Answer (score 0):

No longer works for [anybody](https://www.theverge.com/2017/7/26/16034844/google-kills-off-instant-search-for-mobile-consistency) (:.